# SQL Server : online video training for development

Tags: sql-server

I currently use PluralSight for online video training on .net related technologies. Their videos on .net technology are awesome but I am not satisfied with SQL Server related videos.

Could some one please recommend some paid or free training online video site for SQL Server.

If this is not the right forum to ask this question then where should I ask this question?

I am looking for development training.

Comment: What kind of training?  Development, administration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used webucator.com for an introduction to C#.  It was a great class and taught me quite a bit in 5 days. They have both instructor led and go at your own pace training available. They have a T-SQL class I've had my eye on for a while and plan on taking the next chance I get.